# What non fish items can you get from fishing?

Tags: torchlight-2

I am trying to find if/what items you can get from fishing other than standard fish but I can't find it. Is it possible to fish up gear, gems, etc? If so, where can I find a list of fish able items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can get gear, special ingredients and more from fishing spots. Special ingredients also include fish whichupon their main purpose is not pet-food (for transformation). There are several lists out there on what you can get.

**Here are some of the fishing spot catches**:

- Shimmering Fish Scale (socketable 3 health regeneration. Recover 3 HP per second)
- Gold Fish (wealthy non-food item)
- The Tasty Fish Meat (600 health recovery)
- Sushi Grade Fish Meat (1200 health recovery) may be fed to your pet in the same manner as potions. The Sushi Grade Fish Meat is also used in the creation of a [**Sushi Helm**](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Sushi_Helm). **Sidenote:** The sushi helmet is suberb for fishing as it increases fishing luck.
- Blank's Teeth Necklace (1 socket, +15% to all damage, Random properties, 
  Dungeons are 50% more random)
- Lefferts' Hands (65 armor, 1 socket, +8-10 defense, 7 mana stolen on hit
  +33 all elemental resistances, Increases left-handedness)
- Unidentified boots (Identify to find out!)

There are other type of fish that are only available in specific locations. One must fish everywhere a hole is found, to make sure all fish are found.

Each town (Estherian Enclave, Zeryphesh and Imperial Camp) contains an infinite fishing hole. In other areas of the world, there are Secret Fishing Holes and Promising Fishing Holes. These contain better loot than the fishing hole in town, but only allow a limited number of attempts.

Dynamite can also be used with fishing holes, but yields fewer results / less loot. Dynamite can only be used at fishing holes with a limited number of "attempts," not on the infinite fishing hole in town.

**There are three main types of fishing holes:**

- Fishing Hole (Unlimited casts, located in the main town of each act)
- Promising Fishing Hole (Usually located in an overland area)
- Secret Fishing Hole (Usually located in an overland area, contains special fish, items, tags, and collars)

> [image: While the Gold Fish is indeed a fish, you can sell it instead for a nifty price.] While the Gold Fish is indeed a fish, you can sell it instead for a
>   nifty price.

The lists of what you can get are very, very long. Have a look at these sources for possible catches.

- http://www.runicgamesfansite.com/showwiki.php?title=Fishing
- http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Torchlight/Fish#Other_items_and_equipment
- http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Fishing_Hole
  http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Fishing_Hole

Comment: Two comments: 1) Gold Fish are handy for transferring gold between two of your own characters as you cannot otherwise "stash" gold. 2) Last I checked, fishing luck was a bugged attribute that did nothing, sadly.

Comment: Also, according to your link, the secret horse level is for Torchlight 1, not 2.

Comment: Much of this answer doesn't seem to apply to Torchlght 2.

Comment: Removed section regarding The Secret Horse level as it was indeed in TL1, not TL2. Also updated answer regarding where the fishing holes are and types of reward.